# Drawer navigator v6 drawerPosition:"right". cause some design issue

Tags: android, navigation, react-navigation-v6

when i give drawer position to right then the drawer on right side show 20% even it is close.
[image]

and when i open the drawer its look like this
[image]

my package.js file

```
 "dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.1",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.1.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"num-to-words": "^0.2.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.3",
"react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.3.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.1",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.11",
"react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.0.1",
"react-native-screens": "^3.12.0",
"react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.1.3",
"react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.0.0",
"react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.6",
"redux": "^4.1.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
"words-to-numbers": "^1.5.1"
```

},

Comment: Facing the same issue, upgraded react-navigation v5 to v6.

Answer (score 0):

In Drawer.Navigator Pass **useLegacyImplementation** **true**.

```
<Drawer.Navigator 
    useLegacyImplementation={true}
/>
```

More info about useLegacyImplementation - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#uselegacyimplementation